# Trigger Continuous Integration build in TFS 2017 on root of team project collection

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration

In TFS 2015 it was possible to create an continuous integration trigger in a build definition, that pointed to the root of the team project collection. You could, instead of using the trigger path '$/{team project}', also insert just '$/', which would result in that the continuous integration build triggers on all checkins in that team project collection.

In TFS 2017, it seems to be no longer possible to freely edit this field, and that you can only add a trigger for the team project that the build definition resides in. Is there any other option/possibility to make a build definition trigger on all projects, or at least define the other team projects I want to trigger on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not able to do this in TFS2017.

The build definition is team project level based not collection level.

One workaround is **[Export/Import the Build Definition](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=onlyutkarsh.ExportImportBuildDefinition)** to the other team projects you want to trigger on.

This avoid manually duplicating the definition in another team project/account.
No need to manually add steps and set their values. Just set the trigger path for that team project.